# On my react-native app I'm getting Component Exception API call error of ' Text strings must be rendered within a <Text/>'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, api, node-modules

This is the react-native app, runs without errors when the API is not called, the errors only when I run the API created using NodeJs.
I'm getting the error as API call error
Text strings must be rendered within a  component.

Below is the error shown in the console where I run the react-native app

```
Api call error

Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at ProductContainer.js:125)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at ScrollView.js:1124)
    in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1260)
    in ScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1286)
    in ScrollView (at ProductContainer.js:124)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Container.js:12)
    in Container (at connectStyle.js:392)
    in Styled(Container) (at ProductContainer.js:104)
    in ProductContainer (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)

at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:43:2 in showErrorDialog
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15258:32 in logCapturedError

at [native code]:null in dispatchAction
at Screens\Products\ProductContainer.js:44:10 in axios.get.then$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0        
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Here is the screenShot of the error shown in the Mobile app
[image: mobile app error]

And Code shown in the error is

```
if (!hostContext.isInAParentText) {

    throw Error("Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.");
  }
```

Below provided is the ProductContainer.js Code

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator,
  FlatList,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
} from "react-native";
import { Container, Header, Icon, Item, Input, Text } from "native-base";
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native";
import axios from "axios";

import ProductList from "./ProductList";
import SearchedProduct from "./SearchedProducts";
import Banner from "../../Shared/Banner";
import CategoryFilter from "./CategoryFilter";
import baseURL from "../../assets/common/baseUrl";

var { height } = Dimensions.get("window");

const ProductContainer = (props) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [productsFiltered, setProductsFiltered] = useState([]);
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState();
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [productsCtg, setProductsCtg] = useState([]);
  const [active, setActive] = useState();
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      setFocus(false);
      setActive(-1);

      // Products
      axios
        .get(`${baseURL}products`)
        .then((res) => {
          setProducts(res.data);
          setProductsFiltered(res.data);
          setProductsCtg(res.data);
          setInitialState(res.data);
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Api call error");
        });

      // Categories
      axios
        .get(`${baseURL}categories`)
        .then((res) => {
          setCategories(res.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Api call error");
        });

      return () => {
        setProducts([]);
        setProductsFiltered([]);
        setFocus();
        setCategories([]);
        setActive();
        setInitialState();
      };
    }, [])
  );

  // Product Methods
  const searchProduct = (text) => {
    setProductsFiltered(
      products.filter((i) => i.name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()))
    );
  };

  const openList = () => {
    setFocus(true);
  };

  const onBlur = () => {
    setFocus(false);
  };

  // Categories
  const changeCtg = (ctg) => {
    {
      ctg === "all"
        ? [setProductsCtg(initialState), setActive(true)]
        : [
            setProductsCtg(
              products.filter((i) => i.category._id === ctg),
              setActive(true)
            ),
          ];
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {loading == false ? (
        <Container>
          <Header searchBar rounded>
            <Item>
              <Icon name="ios-search" />
              <Input
                placeholder="Search"
                onFocus={openList}
                onChangeText={(text) => searchProduct(text)}
              />
              {focus == true ? (
                <Icon onPress={onBlur} name="ios-close" />
              ) : null}
            </Item>
          </Header>
          {focus == true ? (
            <SearchedProduct
              navigation={props.navigation}
              productsFiltered={productsFiltered}
            />
          ) : (
            <ScrollView>
              <View>
                for the banner of the home page
                <View>
                  <Banner />
                </View>
                <View>
                  <CategoryFilter
                    categories={categories}
                    categoryFilter={changeCtg}
                    productsCtg={productsCtg}
                    active={active}
                    setActive={setActive}
                  />
                </View>
                {productsCtg.length > 0 ? (
                  <View style={styles.listContainer}>
                    {productsCtg.map((item) => {
                      return (
                        <ProductList
                          navigation={props.navigation}
                          key={item.name}
                          item={item}
                        />
                      );
                    })}
                  </View>
                ) : (
                  <View style={[styles.center, { height: height / 2 }]}>
                    <Text>No products found</Text>
                  </View>
                )}
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
          )}
        </Container>
      ) : (
        // Loading
        <Container style={[styles.center, { backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2" }]}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="red" />
        </Container>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    backgroundColor: "gainsboro",
  },
  listContainer: {
    height: height,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    backgroundColor: "gainsboro",
  },
  center: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

export default ProductContainer;
```

Comment: I think it complains about `<View> for the banner of the home page <View>`

Comment: The `// Loading` line is not actually a comment, it is interpreted as text in JSX and since react-native requires all text to be wrapper in `Text` components it throws that error. Instead use `{/* Loading */}` for inline comments.

Comment: No sir, that was really not helpful, I'm getting the same error, I've researched across google but couldn't resolve my error.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the text in `Text` tag like

```
<View> <Text>for the banner of the home page </Text> <View>
```

Comment: <View> 
  <Text>for the banner of the home page </Text> 
<View>

Answer (score 0):

I solve this error with change my IDE.
When I migrate from VS Code to sublime text or notepad++ or android studio, this error solved.